# htaccess Redirect specific files to other files in same folder if on mobile

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a website hosted by another website as a subdomain. I'm trying to make it mobile friendly. So far I have it correctly redirecting to a mobile version of the site (currently only compatible with Galaxy S3 phone resolutions), which is index_m.php instead of index.php. I have alternate php page files for mobile versions of the aesthetic sections of the site (menu bar, logo, footer, etc). However, when I update I only want to alter one set of files (the actual site content) not two. This works for the most part because I have an alternate menu bar php that sends users to the appropriate mobile pages. The problem is that page sections like updates and highlights that link to various sections of the site are using links to desktop-formatted pages.

Here's my current htaccess content. How can I add another set of conditions for specific files? (Particularly games.php/games_m.php and history.php/history_m.php) which are in the same folder?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# if the browser accepts these mime-types, it's definitely mobile, or pretending to be
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC,OR]

# a bunch of user agent tests
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sony|symbian|nokia|samsung|mobile|windows ce|epoc|opera" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "mini|nitro|j2me|midp-|cldc-|netfront|mot|up\.browser|up\.link|audiovox"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "blackberry|ericsson,|panasonic|philips|sanyo|sharp|sie-"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "portalmmm|blazer|avantgo|danger|palm|series60|palmsource|pocketpc"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "smartphone|rover|ipaq|au-mic,|alcatel|ericy|vodafone\/|wap1\.|wap2\.|iPhone"[NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|ipod|#opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]

RewriteRule ^$ http://sc55.duke4.net/index_m.php [R=302]
```

I know that conventionally one would use an entirely alternate subdomain or subfolder for mobile pages, but as I said I only wish to update one set of files at a time. And I don't have access to any database systems or anything for both websites to pull data from.

Comment: Add `RewriteRule ^/?(games|history)\.php$ http://sc55.duke4.net/$1_m.php [R=302]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, as you probably realize, is that one set of conditions only applies to one rules. How to add rules that follow the same conditions? One solution is to repeat the conditions, but that's too heavy.

The more efficient solution is to use if-then-else logic: negate the conditions, then leave the file untouched and skip the following rules, which therefore apply when the conditions are met. This would look like this:

```
# Do we meet NONE of the conditions?
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} !(text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(sony|symbian|nokia|samsung|mobile|windows ce|epoc|opera) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(mini|nitro|j2me|midp-|cldc-|netfront|mot|up\.browser|up\.link|audiovox) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(blackberry|ericsson,|panasonic|philips|sanyo|sharp|sie) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(portalmmm|blazer|avantgo|danger|palm|series60|palmsource|pocketpc) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(smartphone|rover|ipaq|au-mic,|alcatel|ericy|vodafone\/|wap1\.|wap2\.|iPhone) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(android|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|ipod|#opera mobile|palmos|webos) [NC]

# If so, THEN leave the request untouched (and optionally skip the following rules)
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
# If there are more non-mobile rewrite rules, skip the next two rules by using this instead:
# RewriteRule ^ - [L,S=2]

# ELSE (we meet some of the conditions):
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://sc55.duke4.net/index_m.php [L,R=302]
RewriteRule ^(games|history)\.php http://sc55.duke4.net/$1_m\.php [L,R]
```

Comment: Thank you! I was indeed struggling with how to declare all this. I input your code, but I'm getting an internal server error and the site doesn't load. Is there anything more I have to add to this? I apologize, I'm brand new to htaccess editing. Should I have some sort of declarations for the if's and else's?

Comment: I had a typo on the fifth condition: missing the space here between the `)` and `[NC]`. Try inserting that.

Comment: +1 this should work. @MusicallyInspired: You should always check Apache error.log if you ever get 500 error

Comment: I made the change, but it's still giving me a server error. I don't have access to the error.log file, at least it's not in the same folder as the .htaccess file on the FTP. I'll try contacting the server admin, seeing as I'm just a hosted site on a subdomain.

Comment: Which version did you try to use, the `[L]` or `[L,S=3]`? (Btw it should be `S=2`, seems like I can't count)

Comment: I used the first one with [L]. I have no more non-mobile rewrite rules after those two. Still waiting on that error.log from the admin...

Comment: The error log didn't help me much, however, my server admin (whom I should have gone to in the first place!) suggested I use a custom PHP class to detect a mobile device and put conditional formatting in index.php, games.php, and history.php instead of messing with .htaccess. This way it actually reduces the amount of page maintaining I actually need even more! Thank you so much to those that have responded to help me out, though. I do appreciate it. The PHP class route really is the better option for me here. I blame myself for not considering what PHP was capable of. Still learning Web 2/3.0

Comment: Glad you found something that works for you. See you next time. :)